# How to create own process id in batch (Window)

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, pid

I have a batch script and via that script I have started the logstash. Its running successfully and writing logstash logs in my own file.

```
logstash.bat -f CONFIG_FILE_NAME >> C:\User\logs\agent.log
```

Now I want to create my own **Process Id** for logstash and want to write that **pid** in a file.

I am able to do this in linux by following command.

```
./logstash -f $CONFIG_FILE_NAME --config.reload.automatic > ../logs/agent.log & echo $! >>/$current_dir/$LOGSTASH_FOLDER/agent.pid
```

How can I do that in windows?

Comment: There is a [discussion](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/3577) about adding an option to write a pid-file, but so far developers have been reluctant to do that.  So, I guess, the only option is  to separately run `jps -l` after logstash has started and extract pid value from the output.

Comment: Can you show the logic that's in the `logstach.bat` file or explain from the batch side of that works for the execution of what and how that's triggered? Getting a PID is not hard and possible if you are referring to the actual process id of an executed process. Help me understand some of that and I may be able to help you with this task once I'm 100% certain I understand your process, the logic, etc.